# Run custom script after docker container startup

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, startup

I have the following nodejs dockerfile:

```
# pull image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD node server dev
```

I need to dynamically run a custom JS script inside the container after start up. How can I achieve this?

UPDATE:
I tried adding the following entry point after CMD, but neither CMD not ENTRYPOINT was executed:

```
ENTRYPOINT node customScript.js
```

Added a wrapper shell script (startup.sh) to include both commands:

```
#!/bin/sh

nohup node server dev > startup.log && node data/scripts/custom.js > custom.log
```

Replaced CMD with:

```
CMD ["./startup.sh"]
```

This only executes the first command in the shell and not the second. I also don't see the output-redirect log files being created in the container.

Comment: Can you give an example?  For example, you can write whatever code you want in your application's main function; is that a good place to do the setup you need?  Or can you launch a separate container, or make an HTTP management call from the host, or use an entrypoint wrapper script?  There's lots of options.

Comment: Just add entry point and script name at the end of your script like ENTRYPOINT[“sh”, Abc.sh]

Comment: @DavidMaze, see my update. I cannot run the script in a separate container as it would need a lot of the code from the node container.

Comment: All the code should be in the image, no?  You should be able to `docker run the-same-image some other command` (if you do _not_ use `ENTRYPOINT`).

Comment: @David Maze, can u walk me through this... So I would have to add 'docker run..' command to my dockerfile above? Or do I create a separate docker file just to run the command?

Comment: With the Dockerfile you have originally (again, ending in `CMD`), try `docker run --rm your-image ls -l /app`.  It will print out a directory listing of the code built into the image, in a separate container, then exit and delete the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I understand that the code is available under the /app dir. One of your suggestions was to start a separate container to run the custom script. So,  my question was specifically about how to access the node_modules and files on containerA in containerB without having to install node on containerB.  My custom script is a node script and will require the base node install. Maybe I am completely misunderstanding your point.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I also tried creating a wrapper shell script. I updated OP with the issue I am seeing.

Comment: @sotn It looks like as if you just want to make docker to start two endless processes instead of one. Is that correct? If so, see this: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Answer (score 3):

ideally, you should be running the process of **nohup** in background

there is no issue due to **CMD** or **ENTRYPOINT**

```
#!/bin/sh

nohup node server dev > startup.log && node data/scripts/custom.js > custom.log
```

use **&** last at your **nohup** command to start the process into backgroud mode

```
nohup ./yourscript &
```

**or**

```
nohup command &
```

after this you can run the **node** command

**sh** example

```
nohup nice "$0" "calling_myself" "$@" > $nohup_out &
node index.js
sleep 1
tail -f $nohup_out
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a supervisor to run multiple processes in a single container. They will/may also auto-restart died process again. Without a supervisor, your processes may be messed up.

Ex:

In my case, I use [s6](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/overview.html) in the project [alpine-s6-nginx-php](https://github.com/raxetul/alpine-s6-nginx-php) to run processes in a single container. The project has an OOP-like inheritance model from:

- base the image **alpine-s6-base**
- to **alpine-s6-nginx**
- to **alpine-s6-nginx-php**.

Base image prepares the s6 setup, nginx image adds nginx process and final **alpine-s6-nginx-php** image adds php-fpm7 process. You may check these repos and s6 supervisor.
It is not needed to separate layers for each process, all processes can be added in a single Dockerfile. And also you may use s6 alternatives like systems or etc.

TLDR; you can use [s6-overlay](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay) to build s6 supervised container images easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can add entry point keyword and script name at the end of your script like ENTRYPOINT[“sh”, “Abc.sh”]

Comment: see my update to OP.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run two commands in the docker startup, one should be non-blocking and other can be blocking call.

If both call are blocking then you need to start one command in separate thread/process and then run the other command.

This can be achieved in a parent script(sh) which can start one process for one command and call the last command in current process.

https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/internal.html
https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_01_04.html

Comment: This doesn't appear to be link-only, or anything else worthy of deletion. It's a text-only description of the solution, which is perfectly valid. It's also self-contained, so I'm gonna go ahead and undelete this. You may want to clarify your answer to prevent this mistake in the future